# SO reputation thresholds a bit odd 15, 50, 100 rather than 15, 63, 127

Tags: discussion, status-declined, privileges

In the [SO FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) most of the threshold values seem a bit odd. The pattern of 2<sup>n</sup>-1 is lost and changes to something a bit obscure, x*10<sup>n</sup>. Here is a recommended improvement:

- 15 -> 15
- 50 -> 63
- 100 -> 63 or 127
- 200 -> 255
- 250 -> 255
- 500 -> 511
- 1000 -> 1023
- 2000 -> 2047
- 3000 -> 4095
- 5000 -> 4095
- 10000 -> 8191
- 15000 -> 16383
- 20000 -> 32767

It is obvious that whoever decided upon 15 was the real marketeer, keeping it at 2<sup>3</sup> and some change makes it seem so much easier to attain than 2<sup>4</sup>.

Comment: If this doesn't get fixed within five business days, I am *so* walking out of here.

Comment: @CWH, we now have 5k, 15k and 20k privileges, so maybe you should add 5000 &rarr; 4095, 15000 &rarr; 16383 and 20000 &rarr; 16383 or 32767?

Comment: I asked this way back in the day, but I guess that question was deleted, as I can't find it now...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this was meant as a joke question, and per the tag wiki for [tag:fun], joke questions today should some additional use beyond mere entertainment. In my view, this doesn't have much additional use as it doesn't make much of a concrete argument; if this were instead making some other argument such as "the privilege thresholds for the 5,000 and 20,000 privileges are too low because [x]", it would. Also, the answer has no value.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Your edit here was inappropriate, IMO. The user that edited the [tag:fun] tag out and explained that [tag:fun] wasn't intended was the original author of this question. They, by definition, are the authority of what was intended, unless there's evidence contemporary to the posting of the question that the author did, in fact, intend this as "fun", but I'm not seeing any. Yes, it appears that everyone else may have *assumed* that it was [tag:fun], including Jeff Atwood, who added the [tag:fun] tag, but that doesn't mean that such was the original intent of the author.

Comment: @Sonic you can't and should not guess people feelings, intentions, or thoughts. and of course should not change their posts based on that. Post a comment, downvote if you don't like it. Also, how on Earth this "isn't about Stack Exchange"??? (As the first close voter, and since there is a herd closure here, I'm asking you.)

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard [Responded in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9486040#9486040); let's continue the discussion there.

Comment: @Sonic I'm not there anymore, until further notice. I'm in other room(s) if you want.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard Okay, moved the discussion to Shadow's Den.

Answer (score 11):

Personally I do not think this is taking it far enough.

Rep reqs should all be base-2, and they should be displayed in base-2:

[image: rep req]